# MKMapView looking yellowish, how to change the color?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

The MKMapView looks like this:

```
let viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 200, 200)
mapView.setRegion(viewRegion, animated: false)
```

[image]

I am expecting it to look as this (not yellowish but grayish):

[image]

I am not able to understand how to do the same. Please help me understand how to do the same. I am so stuck at this. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can't change it. I think you might be able to use a dark mode now (not sure if thats MacOS only and not iOS). If you want to change the style or you want a different style you need to use a third party mapping library instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MapKitGoogleStyler` available at https://github.com/fmo91/MapKitGoogleStyler.

`MapKitGoogleStyler` allows you to include `Google Maps JSON styles`, that you can create [here](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/), and customize your `MKMapView` to look just like you want (or your client). Including this library is very very easy.

A post explaining this in detail can be found here: https://medium.com/@ortizfernandomartin/customize-mapkits-mkmapview-with-google-maps-styling-wizard-a5dcc095e19f#.ss3dencgh